# Formatear valor (precio)

Tags: javascript, asp

tengo un problema que me registra en lo siguiente, estoy sumando varios valores de una tabla donde por ejemplo tengo los siguientes valores

15.000 - 56.000 - 85.000 - 25.000 = 181000

```
tabla+="<td>"+"<input id=\"total"+(j+1)+"\"  name=\"total"+(j+1)+"\" value=\""+(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(total))+"\" onchange=\"sumarvalores("+(j+1)+");\" class=\"valores\" onKeyPress=\"return isNumberKey(event)\">"+ "</td>";

tabla+="<td>"+"<input id=\"resultado\"  name=\"spTotal\" value=\""+(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(valorPrecio))+"\">"+ "</td>";

function sumarvalores(valor){
  var nw_var = document.getElementById('total'+valor).value;
  document.getElementById('total'+valor).value= new Intl.NumberFormat().format(nw_var);

  var total1 = 0;
    $(".valores").each(function(){
        if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))){
            total1 += 0;
        }else {
            total1 += parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('resultado').value = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(total1);

}
```

Hasta el momento me realiza la suma como corresponde, pero cuando me entrega el valor final en vez de salir 181.000, me trae como resultado 181, como puedo hacer para que los ceros y el punto me aparezca donde corresponde.  Estoy trabajando en asp y js

Comment: intenta hacer esto document.getElementById('resultado').value  = total1.toFixed(3)

Comment: el problema es que cuando haces por ejemplo `parseFloat(15.000)` queda 15, y no 15000

Comment: He probado lo que me has dicho y si me resulta, me da 181.000, pero cuando ingreso monto mas altos, como por ejemplo 185.000 + 120.000 + 250.000 + 600.000 = 1.155.000, pero me arroja el siguiente valor 1155.000, me falta un punto despues del primer 1

Answer (score 4):

En Javascript (en casi todos los lenguajes de programación, de hecho), el punto es es separador de decimales, por tanto los números que estás poniendo

```
15.000 - 56.000 - 85.000 - 25.000
```

son entendidos como

```
15 - 56 - 85 - 25
```

La solución es quitar los puntos antes de hacer las operaciones:

```js
const num =['15.000','56.000', '85.000', '25.000', '8'];

//el operador + transforma a número
const sinPunto = num.map( number => + number.replace(/\./,''));
console.log(sinPunto.toString());

//sumamos todos
const suma = sinPunto.reduce((resultado, sumando) => resultado + sumando,0);

//usando toLocaleString, podemos poner el punto de vuelta
console.log('Todo suma', suma.toLocaleString('es'));
```